# Is this abstract base class with a "better" __repr__() dangerous?

Tags: python, pickle, signature, abc, repr

It bugs me that the default `__repr__()` for a class is so uninformative:

```
>>> class Opaque(object): pass
... 
>>> Opaque()
<__main__.Opaque object at 0x7f3ac50eba90>
```

... so I've been thinking about how to improve it. After a little consideration, I came up with this abstract base class which leverages the `pickle` protocol's [`__getnewargs__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) method:

```
from abc import abstractmethod

class Repro(object):

    """Abstract base class for objects with informative ``repr()`` behaviour."""

    @abstractmethod
    def __getnewargs__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __repr__(self):
        signature = ", ".join(repr(arg) for arg in self.__getnewargs__())
        return "%s(%s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, signature)
```

Here's a trivial example of its usage:

```
class Transparent(Repro):

    """An example of a ``Repro`` subclass."""

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        return self.args
```

... and the resulting `repr()` behaviour:

```
>>> Transparent("an absurd signature", [1, 2, 3], str)
Transparent('an absurd signature', [1, 2, 3], <type 'str'>)
>>>
```

Now, I can see one reason Python doesn't do this by default straight away - requiring every class to define a `__getnewargs__()` method would be more burdensome than expecting (but not requiring) that it defines a `__repr__()` method.

What I'd like to know is: how dangerous and/or fragile is it? Off-hand, I can't think of anything that could go terribly wrong except that if a `Repro` instance contained itself, you'd get infinite recursion ... but that's solveable, at the cost of making the code above uglier.

What else have I missed?

Comment: `repr` was around *way* before there existed anything such as `__getnewargs__`. Also you are abusing a method. It was introduced by a library module(not the python language core itself) to do a completely different thing. Also what about keyword arguments? In python3 one can have keyword only arguments for constructor.
Also, I do not see any real added benefit from this. Objects that could have a simple string representation *ought* to implement `__repr__` and/or `__str__`. With your method either you still have to reimplement it or you must reimplement `__getnewargs__`.

Comment: There's no real reason to use `__getnewargs__` per se for this, is there?  You could just define a convention whereby an object stores some identifying info in an arbitrary attribute (say `_reprInfo`), and then the `__repr__` just prints `self._reprInfo`.

Comment: @Bakuriu How am I abusing it, though? A correctly implemented subclass of `Repro` will have a correct-as-per-pickle `__getnewargs__()`, which might even be considered an advantage. I realise this won't work for classes with keyword-arg constructors, but I wouldn't use it with those ... actually, I'd avoid keyword arguments in constructors altogether if I could.

Comment: @BrenBarn yes, originally I was thinking of just using something like a `_reprInfo` property ... but is there any harm in doing it this way?

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: There's no real "harm", but as @Bakuriu said, it just creates a needless dependence between the `__repr__` and `__getnewargs__`.  You could just as well overload any other random method like `__pos__` and declare that that method should now be used to return the `__repr__` data, but why?  It doesn't have any advantage, and it just will cause a headache if you later want to use both `__repr__` and the overloaded method for their own separate purposes.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus If you use only in your classes it may be ok. I'm saying about using it as default by the language itself. As I said, if you want to give a certain representation just implement `repr`. If you do not need it then you do not need it and you are addressing a problem that does not exist.

Comment: @BrenBarn are you saying that a correct for Repro `__getnewargs__()` is an incorrect for pickle `__getnewargs__()`, then? If so, I've missed something. Just to be clear: I'm not proposing this as default Python behaviour (I thought I'd already made that clear in the question, to be honest) - just a potential convenience for my own code.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: It may be, but there's no necessary reason it has to be.  I'm just saying that there is no reason to use `__getnewargs__` for this because conceptually it has no connection to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BrenBarn but it *does* have a connection. `__getnewargs__()` is meant to return the arguments required to reconstruct the object, and `repr()` is meant to return a representation that, ideally, can be used to reconstruct the object. I didn't just pick that method out of the sky ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with this whole idea is that there can be some kinds of objects who's state is not fully dependent on the arguments given to its constructor. For a trivial case, consider a class with random state:

```
import random

def A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = random.random()
```

There's no way for this class to correctly implement `__getnewargs__`, and so your implantation of `__repr__` is also impossible. It may be that a class like the one above is not well designed. But `pickle` can handle it with no problems (I assume using the `__reduce__` method inherited from `object`, but my pickle-fu is not enough to say so with certainty).

This is why it is nice that `__repr__` can be coded to do whatever you want. If you want the internal state to be visible, you can make your class's `__repr__` do that. If the object should be opaque, you can do that too. For the class above, I'd probably implement `__repr__` like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<A object with state=%f>" % self.state
```

Comment: That's an excellent counterexample, and one I hadn't considered - thanks! I'll wait before accepting to see if any others crop up ... you never know ...

Comment: Seems to me like this class could implment `__getnewargs` if it also implemented a `__new__` method that accepted a state argument.

Answer (score 4):

If you're into this sort of thing, why not have the arguments automatically picked up from `__init__` by using a decorator?  Then you don't need to burden the user with manually handling them, and you can transparently handle normal method signatures with multiple arguments.  Here's a quick version I came up with:

```
def deco(f):
    def newFunc(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs
        f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return newFunc
class AutoRepr(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        args = ', '.join(repr(arg) for arg in self._args)
        kwargs = ', '.join('{0}={1}'.format(k, repr(v)) for k, v in self._kwargs.iteritems())
        allArgs = ', '.join([args, kwargs]).strip(', ')
        return '{0}({1})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, allArgs)
```

Now you can define subclasses of AutoRepr normally, with normal `__init__` signatures:

```
class Thingy(AutoRepr):
    @deco
    def __init__(self, foo, bar=88):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
```

And the `__repr__` automatically works:

```
>>> Thingy(1, 2)
Thingy(1, 2)
>>> Thingy(10)
Thingy(10)
>>> Thingy(1, bar=2)
Thingy(1, bar=2)
>>> Thingy(bar=1, foo=2)
Thingy(foo=2, bar=1)
>>> Thingy([1, 2, 3], "Some junk")
Thingy([1, 2, 3], 'Some junk')
```

Putting `@deco` on your `__init__` is much easier than writing a whole `__getnewargs__`.  And if you don't even want to have to do that, you could write a metaclass that automatically decorates the `__init__` method in this way.

Comment: That *is* rather elegant, yes ... but it would mean you'd have to update `_args` and `_kwargs` whenever you modified the object. For me, the advantage of using `__getnewargs__()` is that in order to be correct for `pickle`, it has to be correct for `repr` and vice versa, which I think might be less fragile (or at least more likely to break early and conspicuously).

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: A metaclass could check to see if there was a `__getnewargs__` defined and use that to generate a `__repr__()` and otherwise assume that the decorator had been used on the `__init__()`.

Comment: @martineau hmmm ... combining that with BrenBarn's final suggestion above, we'd have a metaclass that either decorates one special method or creates another, based on the existence or otherwise of a third. That's a lot of magic ...

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: If you really want to keep track of the object's state on the fly (so that changes to attributes are reflected in `__repr__` and `__getnewargs__`), just create your own method that manages this, keeping track of state changes, and then have both `__repr__` and `__getnewargs__` call out to that method to get the scoop on what the current state is.

Comment: @BrenBarn interesting idea ... I'll have to go away and think about that. Thanks :-)